# Troubles with regular expressions

Tags: regex, shell

I wanted some help on extended regular expressions.
I have been trying to figure out but in vain

I have a file conflicts.txt which looks like this please note that it is only a part of this file , there are many lines like these

```
Server/core/wildSetting.json
    Server/core
  Client/arcade/src/assets
Client/arcade/src/assets/
  Client/arcade/src/assets
Client/arcade/src/Game/
```

i am writing a shell script which goes thorugh this file line  by line :

```
 if [ -s "$CONFLICTS" ] ; then
   count=0 
   while read LINE
   do
   let count++
   echo -e "\n $LINE \n" 
   done < $CONFLICTS
 fi
```

the above prints the file line by line what i am trying now is to redirect the lines which have a certain text into some other file for that i have modified echo line of the code to :

```
echo -e "\n $LINE \n" | grep -E "Server/game" > newfile.txt
```

My Query :

As we can see there are many lines of the form Server/Core...
I want to write a regular expression and use it in grep, which matches two kind of lines

1) line s containing the ONLY the string "Server/core"  preceeded and suceeded by any number of spaces

2) all the  lines containing the string "assets"

I have written a regular expression for the same but it doesn't work

here my regEx:

```
grep -E   '[^' '*Server/core$] | [assets]'
```

can you please tell me what is the right way of doing it ?

Please note that there can be any number of spaces before and after "Server/core" as this file is a result of parsing a previous file.

Thanks !

Comment: If it doesn't matter what else is in the line and want to match lines with either `Server/core` or `assets`, this should make it: `grep -E "Server/core|assets" file`

Comment: @fedoroqui , this will match line containing Server/core and redirect to my newfile. i want to match the line that contains "Only" "Server/core"

Comment: So match "Server/core" and *not* "assets"? It is not clear from the question.

Comment: @feforoqui i want to match two kinds of lines 
1) the lines containing the string "assets"
2) lines that  contain only the sting "Server/core" preceeded and succeed by any amount of spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what's asked [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208877/troubles-with-regular-expressions/17209141#comment24927651_17208877):

1) the lines containing the string "assets"

```
$ grep "assets" file
       Client/arcade/src/assets
     Client/arcade/src/assets/
       Client/arcade/src/assets
```

2) lines that contain only the sting "Server/core" preceeded and succeed by any amount of space

```
$ grep "^[ ]*Server/core[ ]*$" file
        Server/core
```

Comment: hey fedorqui , this does match
`Server/core` 
however it also matches lines like

`Server/core/x`

`Server/core/y`

Comment: Mmmm not in my computer. Have you tested it?

Comment: My bad , forgot the carrot and $ to mark begining and finish awesome asnwer fedoroqui thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`sed` (Stream EDitor) can solve your problem perfectly.

Try this command `sed -n '/^ *Server\/core\|assets/p' conflicts.txt`.

There is something wrong with your `grep -E '[^' '*Server/core$] | [assets]'`.
The `^` in a squared brackets omits all the strings containing any of the subsequent characters in the brackets.

If you want to perform *in-place* modification, add the `-i` option to the sed command like
`sed -in '/^ *Server\/core\|assets/p' conflicts.txt`

Comment: Thanks Summer_More_More_Tea 
this is exactly what i am looking for :)

Comment: your answer seems to imply that `grep` is unable to do the job and you have to use `sed`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex just needs to be this:

```
assets|^\s*Server/Core\s*$
```

I think sed or awk would be a better tool than grep - you would need to escape the forward slash if you used one of these.

Comment: Dave it will match every line containing 
`Server/core`
will give me additional lines than expected:)

Comment: Sorry - misunderstood your requirements - answer edited to match.